# What credentials do I need to run from my local host in YugaByte DB?

Tags: database, user-interface, yugabytedb

For the admin UI (http://127.0.0.1:7000), I didn’t have to enter any credentials? Is this locked down to only run on the local host machine?

Answer (score 1):

The `http://<any-master-ip>:7000/` and `http://<any-tserver-ip>:9000/` web interfaces currently do not require authentication. They are primarily read-only views for looking at the overall cluster, health of nodes, load, metrics, etc. and do not provide access to the underlying data in the tables, or to drop/create objects.

You can however choose to restrict access to the ports. You can also use a non-loopback address if you want to access the web interface from another node. See the `webserver_interface` gflag described here: https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/admin/yb-master/#config-flags